# Autofs does not show files of Samba dir in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, samba, sharing, autofs

I've been trying to have AutoFS mount a location in my home network **//content/projects** locally in `/mnt/content` but there are no files when navigating there.

If I mount via fstab, there is no problem, this works fine:

```
//content/projects  /mnt/content/  cifs  credentials=/etc/creds/content,uid=localuser,rw 0 0
```

So I added a line in /etc/auto.master :

```
/mnt/content /etc/auto.cifs-shares --timeout 300
```

Then in 'auto.cifs-shares':

```
projects --fstype=cifs,credentials=/etc/creds/content,dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0755,uid=user,rw ://content/projects
```

Edited my /etc/creds/content file:

```
username=smbuser
password=smbpass
```

And finally restarted autofs in a shell via '**sudo automount -f -v**':

```
$ sudo automount -f -v
Starting automounter version 5.1.2, master map /etc/auto.master
using kernel protocol version 5.02
lookup(dir): dir map /etc/auto.master.d missing or not readable
lookup(file): failed to read included master map dir:/etc/auto.master.d
lookup(file): failed to read included master map auto.master
mounted indirect on /mnt/content with timeout 300, freq 75 seconds
```

And yet, 'ls /mnt/content/' shows an empty directory.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by replacing what *may be typos* in your post:

In auto.master:

```
/mnt/content /etc/auto.cifs-shares --timeout=300 --ghost
```

I added a = between timeout and 300, And I added --ghost

In /etc/auto.cifs-shares

```
projects -fstype=cifs,credentials=/etc/creds/content,dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0755,uid=user,rw ://content/projects
```

I replaced --fstype=cifs with -fstype=cifs

***As a side note***: systemd has their own version of autofs if you are interested. It works through fstab. The equivalent based on your fstab statement would look something like this:

```
//content/projects  /mnt/content/  cifs  credentials=/etc/creds/content,uid=localuser,rw,noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.idle-timeout=300 0 0
```

*You might want to change the mount point if you want to experiment with this. Don't know what happens when you have two autofs processes running at the same time on the same mount point.*

`noauto,x-systemd.automount` replaces the "don't mount the share until I access the mount point" part of this.

`x-systemd.idle-timeout=300`replaces the --timeout=300 part in auto.master.

Then you need to reset systemd:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart remote-fs.target
```